# Bitcoin core trying to sign a transaction loaded from psbt file, but getting "could not sign any more inputs" error

Tags: bitcoin-core, raw-transaction, passphrase, signrawtransaction, bip174-psbt

I am trying to sign a transaction loaded from psbt file, but I'm getting `could not sign any more inputs` error.

I did it successfully on the first try. However I cannot do it any more now.

I changed my passphrase of bitcoin-core before I did the second try. Does it matter?

Comment: I am answering the question based on the things we tried and resolved while discussing in chatroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed my passphrase of bitcoin-core before I did the second try. Does it matter?

Yes. Entering the passphrase in console using [`walletpassphrase`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/walletpassphrase/) should resolve the issue